# Best practice - Passing instance variables or using params in Ruby on Rails views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

According to the following example, What's the best practice?

## Case 1

*controller.rb*
...

```
def index
  ...
  @group = params[:group]
  @team = params[:team]
  @org = params[:org]
  ...
end
```

*index.html.haml*

```
= link_to @group, '#'
= link_to @team, '#'
= link_to @org, '#'
```

## Case 2

*controller.rb*
...

```
def index
  ...

  ...
end
```

*index.html.haml*

```
= link_to params[:group], '#'
= link_to params[:team], '#'
= link_to params[:org], '#'
```

Or maybe there is another option, like passing only one instance variable of Hash type...

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

If you have to chose between these two definitely #1, the view shouldn't use the params hash because it is a mix of concerns. It is the role of the controller to deal with the params hash and prepare everything for the view.

I think that an even better practice is not to use instance variables at all, but just to use helper methods in your controllers:

```
def group
    params[:group]
end
helper_method :group
```

And in the view:

```
= link_to group, '#'
```

In this way the method is lazy, only evaluated if used.

Also have a look to

Answer (score 7):

Generally it's a better idea to split out your parameters as instance variables, especially if you need to do some cleaning up on them. Using `params` directly inside a view is a bit messy, and has the effect of needlessly tying the view to the structure of the incoming parameters.

It's the controller's job to intermediate between the incoming parameters and the view itself. It should convert from one format to another so that you can make a change to the parameters without affecting the view, and to the view without changing the requirements for the parameters.

It's unusual to pass through parameters without doing some kind of processing on them. Most of the time, incoming parameters are used to fetch records from a database, or are used in routing in some capacity.

Seeing three parameters being passed in and then used *literally* on the page is not a common use case. Why are you passing these in instead of passing a reference to one of these things that can be used to determine the others?

For example:

```
@team = Team.find_by_slug(params[:team_id])
@org = @team.org
@group = @team.group
```

This is how most Rails applications are constructed.

Comment: I'm filtering User results by group, team and org. When I filter by group, I send in params the group id (params[:group]), then I also want to filter by team (keeping group filter), so I send the params[:group] to the view to be sent in next request with params[:team].